# IEEEtran not showing book title for @inbook or @incollection entry

Tags: bibtex, ieeetran

For some reason my bibliography is not showing the title of the book for my INBOOK entry. 
I am trying to use `crossref` to cross reference the book, but the bibliography only shows the chapter title.

I've also tried using title for the chapter title and booktitle for the book's title, but not no avail.

The referenced book entry is also after the inbook entry ([an apparent requirement](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12095/crossrefs-not-showing-up-in-bibliography-with-biblatex))

This is my bibtex source:

```
@INBOOK{sweetser04,
  pages = {627-637},
  title = {How to Build Evolutionary Algorithms for Games},
  author = {Sweetser, Penny},
  crossref = {aigpw2}
}

@BOOK{aigpw2,
  title = {AI Game Programming Wisdom 2},
  publisher = {Charles River Media},
  year = {2004},
  editor = {Rabin, Steve},
  address = {Hingham, Massachusetts},
  edition = {1}
}
```

The cross reference seems to work but `inbook` is missing the book title and editor:

> Sweetser, Penny, *How to Build Evolutionary Algorithms for Games*, 1st
>   ed. Hingham, Massachusetts: Charles River Media, 2004, pp. 627-637.

and `incollection` is missing the edition and book title:

> Sweetser, Penny, "How to Build Evolutionary Algorithms for Games", S.Rabin, Ed. Hing-
>   ham, Massachusetts: Charles River Media, 2004, pp. 627-637.

I was expecting:

> Sweetser, Penny, "How to Build Evolutionary Algorithms for Games" in *AI Game Programming Wisdom 2*, 1st
>   ed. Hingham, Massachusetts: Charles River Media, 2004, pp. 627-637.

Has anyone else run into this issue using IEEEtran?

I am using BibTex v0.99d with pdfTeX v3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (MikTex 2.9 64bit) with the newest IEEEtran.bst from http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/bibtex/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The crossref feature retrieves missing fields from the referenced item. Therefore, the book should have a `booktitle` field, which can be used in `incollection`. More details can be found in the bibtex manual.

Here's some code that gives what you're looking for:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{refs.bib}
@incollection{sweetser04,
  pages = {627-637},
  title = {How to Build Evolutionary Algorithms for Games},
  author = {Sweetser, Penny},
  crossref = {aigpw2}
}
@book{aigpw2,
  title = {AI Game Programming Wisdom 2},
  booktitle = {AI Game Programming Wisdom 2},
  publisher = {Charles River Media},
  year = {2004},
  editor = {Rabin, Steve},
  address = {Hingham, Massachusetts},
  edition = {1}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

Let's cite something~\cite{sweetser04}.

\bibliography{refs}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How to narrow down the space between "Ed." and "Hingham"? It seems the space is too big to ignore.

Comment: @WangyanLi  This space is a feature of the IEEEtran style. Use something else if you don't like it.