# configure latexmk in Texworks 0.2.3

Tags: latexmk, texworks

Someone told me "You can configure latexmk in 0.2.3 in texworks".  How, please?

(I need it so that compilation is done properly for bibligraphies.)

I'm in Debian 6 and using TexLive.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Go to `Edit`->`Preferences`->`Typesetting` to add `Processing tools`.
Use `latexmk` under `Program` and ensure that you have perl installed. Then go to `Arguments` for further configuration.

If you want to compile via `pdflatex`, use

```
-e
$pdflatex='pdflatex -synctex=1 %S'
-pdf
$fullname
```

If you want to compile via `latex`+`dvipdfm`, use

```
-e
$latex='latex -synctex=1 %S'
-e
$dvipdf='dvipdfm %S'
-pdfdvi
$fullname
```

If you want to compile via `latex`+`dvips`+`ps2pdf`, use

```
-e
$latex='latex -synctex=1 %S'
-e
$dvips='dvips -P pdf -t a4 %S'
-pdfps
$fullname
```

Check the box `View PDF after running`.

The `-synctex=1` flag enables synctex, the ability to jump between source code and output with a right click.

The `-P pdf` option ensures you get a quality pdf output when using `dvips`, while the `-t a4` option takes care of papersize, which may be changed to `-t letter` as appropriate.

For all configuration options, refer to the `latexmk` manual.

Comment: I don't really know what options I should use.  I just know I normally use pdflatex but latexmk is supposed to be ideal for bibliography compilation cause it runs something twice.  Can you tell me how I would simulate the latexmk present by default in version 4?  Which of the above options should I use?

Comment: Nobody has ever explained to me why biblographies need to be run twice before.  Perhaps you can?

Comment: @ptrcao [This answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11123/prevent-pdflatex-from-writing-a-bunch-of-files/11130#11130) has some comments on why you need to run things several times. It might be helpful

Comment: @ptrcao This answer speaks directly to your question: [Undefined citation warnings](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8332/undefined-citation-warnings/8348#8348)

Comment: @WillHunting How can I configure `latex+dvips` ?

Comment: @WillHunting I just want up to the `PS` not the pdf.

Answer (score 3):

You can find all information here: https://github.com/TeXworks/texworks/wiki/AdvancedTypesettingTools

Answer (score 2):

On  my machine with texworks (version 0.5 r.952 (Debian)), latexmk version 4.31, and pdflatex from texlive 2011, the above mentioned solution(s) does not work. But the following works.

```
-pdf 
-pdflatex=pdflatex 
-interaction=nonstopmode 
-synctex=1  
$fullname
```