# pdflatexify in TeXworks

Tags: texworks

In my installation of TeXlive + TeXworks, it has `latexmk`, but I didn't like `latexmk`, because when only a single `pdflatex` is needed, it does some multiple runs. In addition, `latexmk` sometimes does not run multiple times, even when necessary, and `latexmk` is slower than `pdflatex` for a single run.

How can I configure a typeset menu that does simply `pdflatex` + `bibtex` + `pdflatex` + `pdflatex`?

Comment: Why not use the regular `pdflatex` most of the time, and just use `latexmk` when you want to run `bibtex`?

Comment: @Alan It might be the best way.

Comment: @Jasper I maybe had to say, `latexmk` is slower than the simple `pdflatex` even for a single run. Even further, sometimes I needed to force `bibtex`, when only bib file is modified. I can't make it re-happen now, but some weird cases happened.

Comment: @Jasper I don't agree; I find `latexmk` useful in the last stages of document preparation, but not as my everyday typesetting script. Most of the time when you are recompiling a document you don't care much about resolved references etc. but more about whether the content is correct in other ways. And `latexmk` does seem to be slower overall.

Comment: This question is a bit confusing: You mention that you don't like the fact that latexmk does multiple runs, yet the scenario you provide has 4 runs of `pdflatex`.

Comment: @PeterGrill Yes, it was confusing. I revised the question. I ended up with creating a script for 4 runs. Normally I use just `pdflatex` and when needed use the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although your installation has `latexmk`, according to [this link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27314/latexmk-not-accompanying-texworks-0-5) it is no longer packaged as part of TeXWorks as of r865. The reason given for this is that [latemk is not available on all platforms](http://code.google.com/p/texworks/source/detail?r=865).

To manually setup `latexmk` for use with TeXWorks see [configure latexmk in Texworks 0.2.3](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18936/configure-latexmk-in-texworks-0-2-3).

If there are specific cases where you find that `latexmk` does more runs then necessary you should report those so that `latemk` can be enhanced to correct these.