# latexmk not accompanying TexWorks 0.5?

Tags: texlive, texworks, latexmk

I seem to remember latexmk should be included since ver 0.4 TexWorks.  I have ver 0.5 r.930 Debian installed on Deb 6 64 bit.  Also I have Texworks 2011 installed in my home folder.  So why doesn't latexmk appear on the list of typesetting options and how do I get it to?

I prefer to avoid manually setting it up in preferences.  I want it prepackaged.

[image]

Comment: This depends I think on where you got your copy of TeXworks from (the pre-defined list of binaries varies depending on who compiled it). I'm also not clear what's wrong with adding an extra entry.

Comment: I got it from Synaptic.

Comment: I cannot find a version 0.5 At Google there are only sources of 0.4.3 http://code.google.com/p/texworks/

Comment: @Herbert: You can [checkout the sources](http://code.google.com/p/texworks/source/checkout) for the development version 0.5 via Subversion and compile on your own. Works fine for me.

Comment: @Thorsten Donig: Thank you! didn't realized that the development source was different from the tarzip

Answer (score 9, accepted):

LaTeXmk has been removed in [r865 of TeXworks](http://code.google.com/p/texworks/source/detail?r=865). But it should be no big deal to add a new entry to the processing tools.

---

[image]

Comment: Do you know why was it removed?  I remember it was included and worked out of the box around the time when I was using TexWorks 0.4...  That was my whole motive for upgrading TW at the time.  Latexmk is useful and indispensable for any number of packages which require repeat compilations by different processes.

Comment: @ptrcao: If you just follow the link in my answer, you will see possible reasons.