# Referencing subfigure when subfigures are in the same image

Tags: cross-referencing, subfloats

I prefer to design my figures externally such that I only need to include one image in latex, even if it consist in several subfigures. Say, I want to have two figures (a) and (b) side by side. Instead of creating two images (corresponding to (a) and (b)) and including both in the figure environement, I rather create one image with both figures side by side and include only this one in the figure environement.

However, I sometimes did proceed the other way round and came to appreciate the handiness of the `subfig` package that, together with `cleveref`, allows direct and automated referencing of subfigures.

Still, I want to stick to my habit of creating one image rather than two, because I can more easily adjust the position of the subfigures. Is there a way to reference a subfigure that is not explicitely defined as such in latex (because it is defined externally)?

I know that I could do this by hand with using `\ref` and putting an "a" or "b" behind. However, I don't know yet, if I want to have my references in parenthesis or not and this can be easily adjusted by the `cleveref` package at the end. Therefore, I want to keep it as homogeneous as possible.

I am sorry if there is already such a question, but I have absolutely no idea how to search for this. Using my title in the `search` field does give any clue.

Comment: I think the workflow you're describing is going to cause frustration in the long run. Personally, I would create one figure per image, and then use the `subfigure` environment from the excellent `subcaption` package. You can then globally change all of your captions easily, and easily use the `cleverref` package too.

Comment: My `subcaption` package allows labeling build-in subfigures, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40508/redefine-figref-so-that-it-can-accept-optional-arguments

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree that this workflow is not ideal, but one way you can work with what you have is to use empty subfigure environments from the `subcaption` package. I made a new command called `\phantomsubfigure` that accepts a label for the subfigure as the only argument.

## Code:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} %the demo option is set only for this example
\usepackage[]{hyperref}
\usepackage[]{cleveref} %http://www.ctan.org/pkg/cleveref
\usepackage[labelformat=empty,skip=0pt]{subcaption} %http://www.ctan.org/pkg/subcaption

\newcommand*\phantomsubfigure[1]{\begin{subfigure}[]{0pt}\caption{}\label{#1}\end{subfigure}} %<---- this is the command

\begin{document}

Take look at the cow in \cref{1a}, the space ship in \cref{1b}, and finally at the dress in \cref{1c}.

\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{test.jpg}%
\phantomsubfigure{1a}%
\phantomsubfigure{1b}%
\phantomsubfigure{1c}%
\caption{this is a test}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

## Example Output:

[image: example output]

Comment: Thanks, works fine for my purpose. And maybe I should reconsider my workflow, but not for the next two weeks :). How do you usually work? Do you create an image for each subfigure, with same dimensions? Or at least same height? How do you align them? Just by inserting some `\hfill`? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, I create an image for each subfigure. My subfigures are usually data plots from MATLAB with the same dimensions so they basically line themselves up. I usually have two subfigures per row, so I just set the width of each graphic to `.5\linewidth`. http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions#Subfloats might be able to help on ideas for aligning subfigures.

Comment: +1 but I think the order of the packages should be `graphicx`, `hyperref`, `cleveref`

Comment: @cmhughes Thanks for the correction, I've edited the answer to reflect the changes.