# Suppress extra space between figure and caption when using \subfigure

Tags: captions, subfloats

Is there a way to prevent extra space being added between the figure and its caption when using `\subfigure`?

I am using a command posted in [this topic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58565/referencing-subfigure-when-subfigures-are-in-the-same-image/58572#58572) where a `\subfigure` is added using the `\phantomsubfigure` command.

When using this command it adds extra space between my figure and its caption. Is there a way to suppress it?

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[
DIV=11,
%fontsize=12,
twoside=semi, 
headinclude=false,
titlepage=firstiscover,
abstract=true,
headsepline=true,
footsepline=true,
chapterprefix=true, 
headings=big,
bibliography=totoc,
captions=tableheading
]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{afterpage} %to float a figure onto its own page
\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}
\usepackage[labelformat=empty,skip=0pt]{subcaption}


%%%%%%%%%%% PHANTOM SUBFIGURE COMMAND
% Used for adding subfigure referencing capabilities to composite figure images
\newcommand*\phantomsubfigure[1]{\begin{subfigure}[]{0pt}\caption{}\label{#1}\end{subfigure}} %<---- this is the command
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{(\alph{subfigure})}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=16cm,height=23cm]{myPictureName.png}
  \caption{Figure without subfigures.}
  \label{fig:1}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[htb]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=16cm,height=23cm]{myPictureName.png}
  \phantomsubfigure{fig:S01+04-xrd_a}
  \phantomsubfigure{fig:S01+04-xrd_b}
  \phantomsubfigure{fig:S01+04-xrd_c}
  \phantomsubfigure{fig:S01+04-xrd_d}
  \phantomsubfigure{fig:S01+04-xrd_e}
  \caption{Figure with subfigures.}
  \label{fig:2}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You have to type a % after each `\phantomsubfigure` and after the second `\includegraphics` or you put all that stuff on just one line.

Comment: Neither seems to work for me on 2 different editors.

Comment: Scrap that I just made another foolish mistake the % works thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are introducing some spurious white spaces by calling the `subfigure` environment on and on again. This environment is not meant to be called after an `\includegraphics` and therefore does not handle the white space introduced by the new line. You have to end that line with a `%`. I redefined your `\phantomsubfigure` in order to prevent you from this error for all the following occurrences.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass[%
    ,DIV=11
    ,twoside=semi
    ,headinclude=false
    ,headsepline=true
    ,footsepline=true
    ,headings=big
    ]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}
\usepackage[labelformat=empty,skip=0pt]{subcaption}

\newcommand*\phantomsubfigure[1]{\begin{subfigure}{0pt}\caption{}\label{#1}\end{subfigure}\ignorespaces} % put ignore spaces here...
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{(\alph{subfigure})}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[htb]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=16cm,height=23cm]{myPictureName.png}
        \caption{Figure without subfigures.}
        \label{fig:1}
    \end{figure}

    \begin{figure}[htb]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=16cm,height=23cm]{myPictureName.png}% <= this one is mandatory
        \phantomsubfigure{fig:S01+04-xrd_a}
        \phantomsubfigure{fig:S01+04-xrd_b}
        \phantomsubfigure{fig:S01+04-xrd_c}
        \phantomsubfigure{fig:S01+04-xrd_d}
        \phantomsubfigure{fig:S01+04-xrd_e}
        \caption{Figure with subfigures.}
        \label{fig:2}
    \end{figure}    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and solution, I did not know `\ignorespaces` existed. Have a nice day.

Comment: @Fiztban You are welcome. Have fun TeXing!