# Need chemnum style, but have the old TeXLive2009 version

Tags: ubuntu, chemstyle, chemnum

First of all, I am a total beginner with both LaTeX and Ubuntu (and I have no clue about programming etc.), so please explain things in a way that I can follow and thanks in advance for your help and patience.

So... I started writing my Chemistry-thesis with LaTeX (using Ubuntu 12.04, TeXLive2009 from the software center, and TeXmaker) and I am having problems with the numbering of my molecules. I used `chemstyle` and `bpchem`, but somehow the tracking doesn't work properly. Within the schemes the compounds are labelled correctly, whereas in the text it is completely messed up.

I read that the `chemnum` package is better for this job, so I wanted to ask you how I can get this new package running (because it is not included in this TeXLive bundle). Where can I download it, where do I save the file?

Do I need to use the terminal? (reminder: I am really a complete beginner with Linux)

Comment: By far the easiest way to proceed is to install ['vanilla' TeX Live](http://tug.org/texlive/). On Ubuntu, this does require using the Terminal, but it requires only a few steps.

Comment: First of all: yes, you'll most probably need to use the terminal, but there are many tutorials around for the installation of the most recent (2012) version of texlive on Ubuntu systems. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27721/versions-of-texlive-under-ubuntu , http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu or this blog post which provides an automatic installation script:
http://alexkrispin.wordpress.com/2011/08/16/update-a-script-to-automate-the-installation-of-texlive-2011-on-ubuntu/