# Configure Latexmk in TeXworks for automation of bibliography compilation

Tags: bibtex, installing, miktex, texworks, latexmk

I've been using LaTeX for almost four years now, so one could perhaps think I would know how to do this. But I don't. I'm at a complete loss here trying to get `latexmk` and, eventually, `BibTeX` to work.

I'm on a Windows using `TeXWorks`. I tried following [this](http://www.economics.utoronto.ca/osborne/latex/BIBTEX.HTM) example, but with no luck. The issue is the last part - I've tried running it through `pdflatex`, then `BibTeX`and then `pdflatex` a couple of more times by simply changing in the drop-down menu. So I've been trying to get `latexmk` to work, but most guides lose me right away.

I tried following the [installation instructions](http://ctan.mackichan.com/support/latexmk/INSTALL), but realized Perl wasn't installed. So I installed Strawberry Perl. I didn't find `C:\local\bin` so I put the files somewhere else and did step 4. Typing in `perl --version` returns perl 5, version 18. By a similar check, `latexmk` is also installed (which may or may not be because I installed it via the Package Update thing in `MikTeX`).

I then run

```
latexmk paper
latexmk -pv paper
latexmk -pv -ps paper
```

and the last line just pops up a window saying no program was found to open the file. So I try

```
ps2pdf paper.ps paper.pdf
```

but then there are no citations but only question marks.

Then I also found [this](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/thesis/html/latexmk.html) guide which would be neat to get working. But I don't know where to find `latexmk`, and I don't know where to find where to find it either!

Maybe I explained my issue in too much detail, but for what it's worth I've at least tried to solve it on my own. Any help to get this working would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Before you [configure latexmk with TeXworks editor](https://code.google.com/p/texworks/wiki/AdvancedTypesettingTools#latexmk) make sure it's installed properly by typing at [commandline prompt](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/command-prompt-faq#1TC=windows-7) `latexmk -v` or `latexmk -help` to see `10 Nov 2013.Version 4.39`. Another test is Download [bib.tex](http://www.andy-roberts.net/res/writing/latex/bib.tex) and [sample.bib](http://www.andy-roberts.net/res/writing/latex/sample.bib) to folder (Desktop) and open `command prompt` folder path, run `latexmk -pdf bib` to get bib.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the first link @texenthusiast! That looks like what I've been looking for. `latexmk -v` returns that string. When following the setup guide in your link, it afterwards say that "latexmk is not properly configured". I guess that's not referring to latexmk itself, but my typesetting tool. In the link, it says `Program:   latexmk` but I don't know where to find this. Would you know how I would locate this? I'm assuming it's the .exe file?

Comment: @texenthusiast The second test worked! So I guess it's all "there", I just need to get it to start working with texworks...

Comment: Normally TeXworks has `LaTeXmk` programm near to the `Typeset` Button (if you scroll down the options) and it detects the MiKTeX bin path (No exact Idea, as I am on Linux).  In the `Edit`-->`Preferences`-->`Typesetting`-->`Paths for TeX related Systems`--> Add the MiKTeX bin path something like `C:\Program Files (86)\MikTeX 2.9\miktex\bin` depending on where you installed miktex

Comment: @texenthusiast Thanks! It seems like it can't find the file. But I tried to manually compile my document using pdflatex, bibtex, pdflatex and then pdflatex again in the dropdown menu in Texworks and it worked and gave me my citations. Perhaps I don't need latexmk, if I just could get this sequence of compilations into some sort of code so I could add it as a typesetting tool that would be enough. Would you happen to know how to write that? If you want you can post it as an answer instead of a comment, so I can accept it too. Thanks for you help and patience with me :)

Comment: Since `LaTeXmk -pdf bib` works all fine (as `perl` was installed properly) from commandline prompt, then it should work from TeXworks editor also, basically `latexmk` it's a perl script made for automation of sequence (pdflatex, bibtex, pdflatex and then pdflatex) that will make life easier and simple. Follow https://code.google.com/p/texworks/wiki/AdvancedTypesettingTools#latexmk it should be ok.

Comment: @texenthusiast It didn't work before, but I typed the code from that link in again and now it worked!! Beautiful, thanks a lot. You're my new hero!!

Comment: Great news!. BTW you don't need to run latexmk multiple times `latexmk paper
latexmk -pv paper
latexmk -pv -ps paper` as seen in your Q, it's 1 run enough. In documentation of [latexmk](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/latexmk) one might find extra information to configure for `latex-dvips-ps2pdf` compilation sequence but TeXworks is more defaults automated for `pdflatex` engine compilation which is good. I will make an answer summarizing all comments in few hrs.

Comment: Related/Duplicate of [configure latexmk in Texworks 0.2.3](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/18936/15717)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run `Latexmk` on MiKTeX Windows with TeXworks editor:

**Step 1**: [perl](http://www.perl.org/get.html#win32) need to be installed. Since it's already installed by you. Make sure it's installed properly by typing at [commandline prompt](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/open-a-command-prompt-window) `latexmk -v` or `latexmk -help` to see [current version](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/latexmk) `10 Nov 2013.Version 4.39`.

Also another test is using example files from http://www.andy-roberts.net. Download [bib.tex](http://www.andy-roberts.net/res/writing/latex/bib.tex) and [sample.bib](http://www.andy-roberts.net/res/writing/latex/sample.bib) to folder (`Desktop`) and open command prompt with Desktop folder path, run `latexmk -pdf bib` to get `bib.pdf`.

**Step 2**: Once `latexmk -pdf bib` works all fine (as perl was installed properly) from commandline prompt, then it should work from TeXworks editor also. Now Configure TeXworks editor to `Latexmk` from wiki guide of TeXworks 
https://code.google.com/p/texworks/wiki/AdvancedTypesettingTools#latexmk

**Step 3**: Normally TeXworks has `LaTeXmk` near to the `Typeset` Button in scroll down the options and it detects the MiKTeX bin path, if not Go to  `Edit`-->`Preferences`-->`Typesetting`-->`Paths for TeX related Systems`--> Add the MiKTeX bin path something like `C:\Program Files (86)\MikTeX 2.9\miktex\bin` depending on where you installed miktex or typein `Path` at commandline prompt to see it's path

Note: BTW you don't need to run `latexmk` multiple times `latexmk paper latexmk -pv paper latexmk -pv -ps paper` as seen in your Q, it's 1 run enough. Basically `latexmk` is a perl script for automation of compilation sequence (`pdflatex`, `bibtex`,`pdflatex` and then `pdflatex` again).