# Undefined Reference Errors in Miktex

Tags: errors, cross-referencing, miktex, warnings

I have been getting weird undefined reference errors to 'Last Page' that point to the line corresponding to my end{document}. I have no idea what this means, but in any case, here is a minimum working example.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,UKenglish]{lipics-v2016}
\begin{document}
\begin{abstract}
Abstract \ldots
\end{abstract}
\end{document}
```

This produces the following: "LaTeX Warning: Reference `LastPage'", "Package lastpage Warning: Rerun to get the references right on input line". I also get things like "LaTeX Warning: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right." no matter how many times I rerun LaTeX. Any advice? I am using Miktex 2.9.

Note: The lipics-v2016.cls file is very large, but can be downloaded here http://drops.dagstuhl.de/styles/lipics-v2016/lipics-v2016-authors.tgz

Edit: I also get the above errors on the starter files without even making changes. This leads me to believe it may be an issue with Miktex. I noticed that Miktex is not producing any .aux or .bbl or .log files... which may be the cause of the error. If I include a bibliography, then no matter what I do, each reference causes a warning.

Comment: How exactly do you run (pdf)LaTeX on your document?

Comment: I just click the typeset button with the options 'pdflatex + makeindex + bibtex'.

Comment: Hm. What if you try with just pdfLaTeX? Does the `.aux` file end up in a subfolder? The warning (it's not an error, just a warning) is gone on the second compilation run when I test it here.

Comment: if you (or your editor) are removing the aux file then the cross reference warning will never go, so ignore the warning, and work out where the aux file went.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Using just pdfLaTeX creates all of the required files and then the warning appear to go away after the second typeset, as expected... Why would this cause an issue? I am so puzzled.

Comment: I can only guess that `texify` (the program I think is used with the `pdflatex+Makeindex+bibtex` option) does something wrong, but other than that I can't say what happens. For now you can use just `pdfLaTeX` I suppose, and then run BibTeX manually when needed. Or you could try configuring TeXworks to use `latexmk` instead (see e.g. [configure latexmk in Texworks 0.2.3](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/18936)). `latexmk` is a different tool for automating compilation.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I was getting fatal errors with texify in a previous version of Miktex, and then I ended up uninstalling it, and updating to Mixtex 2.9 - So now it seems I am still getting 'silent errors' of sorts. I will take a look at the link you provided.

Comment: Even reinstalling Miktex several times did not resolve this issue. I have been running them one at a time since. I am guessing that there is some corrupt file somewhere not being removed by the uninstall process, but wouldn't even know where to begin. For now, I am able to do the work that I need to do, so I haven't been actively trying to resolve the issue.