# How would I cite a dataset from BibDesk on Beamer presentation?

Tags: beamer, texshop, bibdesk

I manage my bibliography using *BibDesk* on *Mac OS X*.

I have a presentation using *Beamer* on which I would like to include some bibliographies. I am using *TeXShop* to do that.

What I know is that I have to put the `.bib` near my `.tex` file to compile, and use `\cite{}` to cite articles. Here is what I have done so far, I created a frame called *Bibliographie*. I cited an article *Gordillo:2013aa*. And I mentionned the path to my centralized `.bib`.

```
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Bibliographie}

sds \cite{Gordillo:2013aa}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{/Users/Alji/Google Drive/Recherche/Papers/LibraryBibDesk.bib}

\end{frame}
```

----> It does not work under TexShop, I get this : 
[image]

I am looking for a general explanation that help me understand the way things work. I found it here [How do I use my .bib file with TexShop](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51499/how-do-i-use-my-bib-file-with-texshop) but I am still having problems ...

Thank you in advance

Comment: This is solved my problem : 

 - http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51499/how-do-i-use-my-bib-file-with-texshop
 - http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159087/how-can-i-put-a-white-space-in-the-path-to-bib-while-compiling-bibtex?noredirect=1#comment363220_159087

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you compile your document you will need to also compile the bibliography. In TexShop there is a drop-down menu that defaults to LaTeX change it to BibTeX and press typeset (I usually do this twice). Then recompile your document with LaTeX twice and your reference should appear or errors on the BibTeX step.

Answer (score 0):

you can typeset tex file, typeset it again wit bibtex, then typeset it twice **OR** using **[image: macro]** in TeXShop that will do all these steps for you