# How can I put a white-space in the Path to .bib while compiling BibTex ?

Tags: bibtex, paths

I have a white-space in the Path to my `.bib` ... The Path is : `/Users/Alji/Google Drive/Recherche/Papers/LibraryBibDesk.bib`

When I compile `BibTex` I get the following error when I compile `BibTex` :

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2013)
The top-level auxiliary file: syn-mseg.aux
The style file: plain.bst
White space in argument---line 164 of file syn-mseg.aux
 : \bibdata{/Users/Alji/Google\
 :                              Drive/Recherche/Papers/LibraryBibDesk.bib}
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
I found no database files---while reading file syn-mseg.aux
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "Gordillo:2013aa"
(There were 2 error messages)
```

any help is a welcome ?

Comment: Do I have to use Hard-Links ?

Comment: BibTeX doesn't want a space in the argument of `\bibdata` (that comes from `\bibliographystyle`). Adding a backslash in front of the space is useless, I'm afraid. Can't you rename the folder? However, a ***soft*** link should work.

Comment: I can't rename the folder because it is a synchronized folder ...

Comment: See http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/8606/how-do-i-create-a-symbolic-link-to-a-directory-with-a-space-in-it for creating a symbolic link.

Comment: I renamed the synchronized folder, I worked ... You can specify that as an answer and I will validate it :) thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BibTeX was created several years ago, when file systems were much more rigid than they are now. I believe that the restriction about not having spaces in the argument of `\bibdata` (that is created in the `.aux` file by a `\bibliographystyle` command) was introduced in order to catch user's input errors, but there might be more compelling reasons.

Anyway, you can solve your problem in a number of ways:

1. rename the folder not to contain spaces (this may cause problems if other software requires that precise name)
2. create a symbolic link to it, say with

   ```
   ln -s ~/Google\ Drive ~/GoogleDriveNoSpace
   ```

   from the terminal, and refer to `GoogleDriveNoSpace` in the path.
3. set `BSTINPUTS` in the environment (this might be the most difficult)

   ```
   export BSTINPUTS="~/Google Drive//":
   ```

See also https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/8606/how-do-i-create-a-symbolic-link-to-a-directory-with-a-space-in-it for more information about symbolic links.