# How can I put a white-space in the Path to .bib while compiling BibTeX? Continued

Tags: bibtex, paths

I am trying to compile a `.tex` file (`beamer` class), and I want to use references from a `.bib` file. This `.bib` file is located in a folder with a path with multiple white spaces in it. Basically I have the same question posed in [How can I put a white-space in the Path to .bib while compiling BibTex ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159087/how-can-i-put-a-white-space-in-the-path-to-bib-while-compiling-bibtex). I know I can remove the white spaces by renaming some folders, or copy the .bib file to the same folder as my `.tex` file, but I would like to solve this in a different way (among others to avoid having multiple .bib files).

What I would like to do is make a symbolic link but I don't know how to, literally what to type where. The method is described [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/8606/how-do-i-create-a-symbolic-link-to-a-directory-with-a-space-in-it) and [here](http://blog.philotropes.org/post/2007/08/18/217-how-to-change-the-location-of-your-bibtex-file-in-latex) as well, but so far I haven't gotten it to work.

I work on a mac using TexShop. I have tried (a lot of variations on) the following: typing `ln -s "/Users/myname/path with spaces"/ biblocation` from my terminal. In my .tex file I put `\bibliography{/biblocation/bibfile}`. This does not work, when compiling the `.bib` file I get:

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2012)
The top-level auxiliary file: presentation_1.aux
The style file: abbrv.bst
I couldn't open database file /biblocation/bibfile.bib
---line 40 of file presentation_1.aux
 : \bibdata{/biblocation/bibfile}
 :                              }
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
I found no database files---while reading file presentation_1.aux
```

The problem is that I just copied this from the answers I found so I don't know what any of it means and I haven't been able to find a good explanation. Do I understand correctly that the `ln -s` command creates kind of a shortcut (symbolic link) for the path entered after it, with 'biblocation' being that shortcut? How can I then use this symbolic link in my tex code?

I hope I explained my question clearly, any help is welcome. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Some LaTeX implementations support paths with spaces. Put path between quotes, ", or extract the correct Mac compliant path name using terminal (for example, in Linux you use `\`  for a space " ") and put that.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond. How do I extract the 'Mac compliant path name'?

Comment: In addition to the above: I have tried this. I dragged the .bib file to the terminal, and copied the path into my .tex file. This path indeed replaced the spaces " " with "\ ", but using this path still resulted in an error during compiling. Enclosing the path in " " also did not help. In both cases I got the error: "White space in argument---line 44 of file presentation_1.aux"