# Automatically run BibTex with LaTeX?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, mac, texshop

Writing a research paper with a bunch of different sources. Is it possible to automatically compile my `bibliography.bib` with my `paper.tex`?

Currently I have to manually follow the answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/51501/176230), which is time consuming, repetitive, and inconvenient.

It it possible to set up TexShop so that instead of:

1. Run LaTeX
2. Run BibTex
3. Run LaTeX
4. Run LaTeX

I can just:

1. Run LaTeX

Comment: Instead of manually running all these steps, you could use one of the latex automation tools like arara, latexmk or ltx2any. With arara you can specify in your document which steps should be executed if you compile your document, the other two will automatically determine which steps are necessary and run them as needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`latexmk`](https://mg.readthedocs.io/latexmk.html). From the prompt, type:

```
latexmk -pdf your_file_here.tex
```

Replace the `-pdf` flag with (e.g.) `-xelatex` if you're using xelatex.

I generally run `latexmk` with `-pvc` (automatic re-compilation when input file changes) and `--silent` (less verbose output). Thus:

`latexmk -pvc -pdf your_file_here.tex --silent`