# Reference issue: In-text references appearing as bold question marks in LaTeX (but not Overleaf)?

Tags: bibtex, apacite

hope you are well!

I usually use "Overleaf" but recently I decided to switch to the offline version - LaTex. And, I am encountering this issue with references appearing as bold question marks "**????**". Do you know how to solve this? I've been reading and trying different things from the LaTeX forum but haven't been able to solve it. Thank you

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{times} % these two packages "times" and "mathptmx" are for "times new roman" font, if you dont want these font, then delete these 2 packages

\usepackage{apacite} %for citations in APA style

\usepackage{etoolbox} %for bibliography

\usepackage{graphicx,url}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  

\usepackage{placeins}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage{natbib}

\typeout{}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
 \bibliography{bibfile}
 
\title{Bibliography management: \texttt{natbib} package}


\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage{color}

\usepackage[affil-it]{authblk}

\usepackage{soul}

\usepackage{booktabs} %For Tables

\usepackage{float} %For Tables

\usepackage{graphicx} %For Tables

\usepackage{caption} %For Tables

\usepackage{lscape} %for Tables 

\usepackage{blindtext}

\pagestyle{plain}
 

\begin{document} 



\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{References}

\begin{flushleft}
    \raggedbottom
     \bibliographystyle{apalike}
  \bibliography{bibfile}
\end{flushleft}
\end{document}*
```

Comment: you didn't run bibtex.

Comment: Exactly which editor are you using with the offline version you have installed.

Comment: you need to run pdflatex then bibtex then pdflatex again (overleaf does this for you)

Comment: You should also not use `\usepackage{apacite}` and `\usepackage{natbib}` in the same document. Rather, load `apacite` with the option `usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}`, which will automatically load `natbib` with the correct compatibility options.

Comment: @daleif i am using TeXShop 4.64

Comment: @UlrikeFischer how do I run BibTeX and pdftex?

Comment: @ManuelWeinkauf i tried that, but it didnt fix the issue

Comment: There should be a button or an item for it on a menu. Not on a Mac, so cannot help further.

Comment: @RachelBrann Yeah, well, the TeXShop documentation is not the best. However, [on their webpage](https://pages.uoregon.edu/koch/texshop/) it seems there is a dropdown menu (the one that says "LaTeX" in the background window of the image they show). Can you switch this to "BibTeX" maybe? You then must run "LaTeX" -> "BibTeX" -> "LaTeX" -> "LaTeX" and all _should_ be fine. For further details, compare [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51499/how-do-i-use-my-bib-file-with-texshop).

Comment: There are helper programs that you can use to ensure the compilation calls all the requisite programs the right number of times to get the output to build. You can configure TeXShop to use them. [This solution using pdflatexmk](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/323539/119) or [this version using arara](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/175671/how-to-use-arara-with-texshop) are probably easier than trying to do the "right number of compilations" by hand every time.