# \cite ouputs a (?) at the pdf

Tags: biblatex, citing

I'm extremely new to LaTeX, and I'm using the PhD template found at http://openwetware.org/wiki/LaTeX_template_for_PhD_thesis  My problem is that after I included my `.bib` archive into the specified folder (I used the same way they use as to prevent any error) I can't seem to get any cite to work: I write `\cite{mycite}` but the PDF output is just a **(?)** and on the references page I don't see any of my citations contained on my `.bib` file. Can anyone help me? I'm really lost and this is extremely important.

Comment: Did you run BibTeX after running LaTeX, then run LaTeX again twice _after_ running BibTeX?

Comment: Depending on your editor, you might already have `latexmk` included, which will take care of all necessary compilation steps.

Comment: Have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8348/3240

Comment: i created my bib file using bibdesk, and then just exported the file to the folder replaced the bib file included with the template.

Comment: Should we mark this a dupe of the question @Thorsten linked to?

Comment: @Q_ro See the link given: you have to run BibTeX to send the information to LaTeX. It does not appear 'by magic'.

Comment: i read the link, but i dont get it, i mean, the template was working perfectly without me having to run bibdesk first, it came with a bib file by default that had some generic citations which where shown on the pdf with no problem, when i generate the pdf i get no errors on texmaker, but all my cites appear as a "(?)".

Comment: @Q_ro: you may be confused because of the close resemblance of the names `bibdesk` and `BibTeX`: The former is a program that creates a `.bib` file, while the latter is a program that needs to be run to process the information (i.e., some or all of the entries) in the `.bib` file in order to create the formatted list of the items that will be shown in the bibliography. In short, after you've created a bibliography with `bibdesk`, you needn't run `bibdesk` again but you will have to run `BibTeX`, in the sequence described by Joseph Wright in his first comment: latex -> bibtex -> latex -> latex.

Comment: Thanks mico, this solved my problem i was a little lost, again, i'm really new to this, and had no prior, but whit your help i was able to succeed, thanks, i really appreciate it.