# How to typeset the whole article efficiently?

Tags: bibliographies, compiling

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Undefined citation warnings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8332/undefined-citation-warnings)
>   [Question mark instead of citation number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63852/question-mark-instead-of-citation-number)

I am a new user of LaTeX. I am writing a paper using TeXworks, using Jabref for the bibliography. I had to typeset so many times to get my article to have correct citation format, otherwise it's showing me a question (?) mark! Sometimes, I had to close all the files and re-open them to get correct output. Sometimes it's not working.

Can anyone please give me any idea to resolve the issue? It's really time consuming having to typeset again and again but not getting the output. In fact, I even don't know in which conditions this happens.

Comment: Duplicate of [Undefined citation warnings](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8332/2693)

Comment: If you're looking for a way to automate the compilation, take a look at this question: [Configure latexmk in TeXworks](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/18936/2693).

Comment: thank you alan munn. but my prob;em is not yet resolved following the way you described here. any other advice?

Comment: @Nusrat If none of the advice here is working, then you need to give us much more specific information about what you are doing.  Does this happen on all documents or just one particular one? Given the first question I linked to, you will minimally need to run `latex bibtex latex latex` to get correct references on any document.  If you're doing that and *still* having problems, then there's more you're not telling us. If you want to add more information, you can do so by editing your question.