# Question mark or bold citation key instead of citation number

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, bibliographies, citing, warnings

I've browsed the forums and found a number of posts that have addressed this issue, but none of the solutions seem to work for me. I have the following script that I just copied from the bibtex home page to get familiar with it. Instead of the citation number I get a question mark. I compile using Latex+Bibtex+Latex+Latex+PDFLatex+ViewPDF just as has been previously suggested and the problem persists.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{cite}

\begin{document}

\title{My Article}
\author{Nobody Jr.}
\date{Today}
\maketitle

Blablabla said Nobody ~\cite{Nobody06}.

\bibliography{mybib}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\end{document}
```

My bibliography (Bib.bbl)

```
@misc{ Nobody06,
author = "Nobody Jr",
title = "My Article",
year = "2006" }
```

Looking at previous posts one thing that is concerning is that my .bbl looks empty as shown below. Further, I don't have a .blg

```
\begin{thebibliography}{}

\end{thebibliography}
```

Comment: not addressing the question itself, ..., but if the `~` before `\cite` is intended to keep the cross-reference from being broken to a new line, the input shown -- `Nobody ~\cite` -- won't do that.  the space character preceding the `~` will (1) happily allow a line break, and (2) double the width of the space before the xref when it's printed.  should be `Nobody~\cite` to have the no-break effect.

Answer (score 243, accepted):

Since this question comes up so often, I thought I'd try to supplement [ArTourter's correct answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/63853/) with a more general comment.

#### What does a question mark mean

It means that somewhere along the line the combination of LaTeX and BibTeX has failed to find and format the citation data you need for the citation: LaTeX can see you want to cite something, but doesn't know how to do so.

#### Missing citations show up differently in `biblatex`

If you are using `biblatex` you will not see a question mark, but instead you will see your citation key in bold.  For example, if you have an item in your `.bib` file with the key `Jones1999` you will see **Jones1999** in your PDF.

### How does this all work

To work out what's happening, you need to understand how the process is (supposed to) work. Imagine LaTeX and BibTeX as two separate people. LaTeX is a typesetter. BibTeX is an archivist. Roughly the process is supposed to run as follows:

1. LaTeX (the typesetter) reads the manuscript through and gives three pieces of information to BibTeX (the archivist): a list of the references that need to be cited, extracted from the `\cite` commands; a note of a file where those references can be found, extracted from the `\bibliography` command; a note of the sort of formatting required, extracted from the `\bibliographystyle` command.
2. BibTeX then goes off, looks up the data in the file it has been told to read, consults a file that tells it how to format the data, and generates a new file containing that data in a form that has been organised so that LaTeX can use it (the `.bbl` file).
3. LaTeX then has to take that data and typeset the document - and may indeed need more than one 'run' to do so properly (because there may be internal relationships within the data, or with the rest of the manuscript, which BibTeX neither knows or cares about, but which matter for typesetting.

Your question-mark tells you that something has gone wrong with this process.

#### More `biblatex` and `biber` notes

- If you are using `biblatex`, the style information is located in the options passed to the to the `biblatex` package, and the raw data is in the `\addbibresource` command.
- If you are using `biber`, the stage described as BibTeX in this answer is generally replaced with a different, and more cunning, archivist, Biber.

#### What to do

The first thing to do is to make sure that you have actually gone through the whole process at least once: that is why, to deal with any new citation, you will always need at least a LaTeX run (to prepare the information that needs to be handed to BibTeX), one BibTeX run, and one or more subsequent LaTeX runs. So first, make sure you have done that. Please notice, that `latex` and `bibtex`/`biber` need to be run on your main file (without the file ending). In other words, the basename of your main file: you do **not** run any commands on the `.bib` file.

```
latex MainFile
bibtex MainFile
latex MainFile
latex MainFile
```

If you still have problems, then something has gone wrong somewhere. And it's nearly always something about the flow of information.

Your first port of call is the BibTeX log (`.blg`) file. That will usually give you the information you need to diagnose the problem. So open that file (which will be called `blah.blg` where 'blah' is the name of your source file).

In a roughly logical order:

1. BibTeX did not find the **style file**. That's the file that tells it how to format references. In this case you will have an *error*, and BibTeX will complain `I couldn't open the style file badstyle.bst`. If you are trying to use a standard style, that's almost certainly because you have not spelled the style correctly in your `\bibliographystyle` command - so go and check that. If you are trying to use a non-standard style, it's probably because you've put it somewhere TeX can't find it. (For testing purposes, I find, it's wise to remember that it will always be found if it's in the same directory as your source file; but if you are installing using the facilities of your TeX system -- as an inexperienced person should be - you are unlikely to get that problem.)
2. BibTeX did not find the **database file**. That's the `.bib` file containing the data. In that case the log file will say `I couldn't open database file badfile.bib`, and will then warn you that it didn't find database files. The cure is the same: go back and check you have spelled the filename correctly, and that it is somewhere TeX can find it (if in doubt, put it in the folder with your source file).
3. BibTeX found the file, but it **doesn't contain citation data** for the thing you are trying cite. Now you will just get, in the log-file: `Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "yourcitation"`. That's what happened to you. You might think that you should have got a type 2 error: but you didn't because as it happens there is a file called `mybib.bib` hanging around on the system (as `kpsewhich mybib.bib` will reveal) -- so BibTeX found where it was supposed to look, but couldn't find the data it needed there. But essentially the order of diagnosis is the same: check you have the right file name in your `\bibliography` command. If that's all right, then there is something wrong with that file, or with your citation command. The most likely error here is that you've either forgotten to include the data in your `.bib` file, or you have more than one `.bib` file that you use and you've sent BibTeX to the wrong one, or you've mis-spelled the citation label (e.g. you've done `\cite{nobdoy06}` for `\cite{nobody06}`.
4. There's something wrong with the formatting of your entry in the `.bib` file. That's not uncommon: it's easy (for instance) to forget a comma. In that case you should have errors from BibTeX, and in particular something like `I was expecting a ',' or a '}'` and you will be told that it was `skipping whatever remains of this entry`. Whether that actually stops any citation being produced may depend on the error; I think BibTeX usually manages to produce something -- but `biblatex` can get totally stumped. Anyway, check and correct the particular entry.

#### `biblatex` and `biber` notes

If you are using `biblatex`, then generally you will also be using the Biber program instead of BibTeX program to process your bibliography, but the same general principles apply. Hence the compilation sequence becomes

```
latex MainFile
biber MainFile
latex MainFile
latex MainFile
```

#### Summary

The order of diagnosis is as follows:

1. Have I run LaTex, BibTeX (or Biber), LaTeX, LaTeX?
2. Look at the `.blg` file, which will help mightily in answering the following questions.
3. Has BibTeX/Biber found my style file? (Check whether you have a valid `\bibliographystyle` command and that there is a `.bst` with the same name where it can be found.)
4. Has BibTeX/Biber found my database? (Check the `\bibliography` names it correctly and it is able to be found.)
5. Has it found the *right* database?
6. Does the database contain an entry which matches the citation I have actually typed?
7. Is that entry valid?
8. Finally: When you have changed something, don't forget that you will need to go through the same LaTeX -- BibTeX (or Biber) -- LaTeX -- LaTeX run all over again to get it straight. (That's not actually quite true: but until you have more of a feel for the process it's a safe assumption to make.)

Comment: You say it in the first sentence, this question comes very often and now I know where to send people looking for an answer...

Comment: fwiw, i'll scrape the answer to improve the faq answer on the same topic (the current faq answer doesn't even touch on biblatex/biber, since i've never used either...).  my reuse doesn't add much to the coverage of your work, but it helps me -- ok?

Comment: In my case, in most of the times was a missing colon (,),  quotation mark ("), or a wrong field.

Comment: Thank you very much for the concise explanation. I have always seen the command with several latex but never understood the reason behind it.

Comment: Another edge-case that may be worth mentioning: if you have multiple bibliography databases (as in `\bibliography{file1,file2}`) all the files need to exist, even if in practice you don't use any records from some.

Comment: Is there a way to automate this? I don't want to have to run latex, then bibtex, then latex twice, everytime I cite something new.

Comment: @becko There are a few options for checking your bib files for errors: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/173622/69025

Comment: @becko latexmk will allow you to write makefiles that automate at least part of the workflow

Comment: There is one common mistake missing: ``I couldn't open file name `mybib.aux'``, because the user called "`bibtex mybib`" instead of "`bibtex MainFile`".

Comment: @Schweinebacke. Thanks. Added.

Comment: Only if I could upvote this answer more than once!
Thanks @PaulStanley

Answer (score 27):

The syntax for the `\bibliography{}` command is `\bibliography{file1,file2,...}`

in your case you seem to be calling a file called `mybib` when your bib file is in fact `Bib`.

Also note that bibtex file should have the `.bib` extension. the `.bbl` file will be created by bibtex.

You should therefore rename your bibliography file `mybib.bib`  and get rid of the extra `{}` in the `\bibliography{mybib}{}` call, and then recompile. This should fix your problem.

Comment: *note*: if you don't see a `.blg` file, you likely have not run bibtex yet.

latex doesn't process the .bib file directly: it needs to be run once (to create its list of requests for `bibtex`, then you need to run bibtex to process this list and deliver the requests. Then you can run latex again and it can incorporate these into your output pdf.

So assuming a masterfile called `masterfile.tex`, you need to

latex masterfile; bibtex masterfile; latex masterfile

Second time, latex will have the files it needs to insert bibtex's output into its own latex output…

Answer (score 2):

Just one little additional comment. I had the same issue for many days and I struggled to find the solution. Finally, I realized that in the .cls file I had the following library

```
\RequirePackage{chapterbib}
```

which I deleted and the problem was solved.

Comment: please add more info