# BibTex There were undefined references

Tags: bibtex, citing, miktex, texmaker

This is the first time I try to use Bibtex for my thesis and I am quite desperate because I cannot get it running.
Despite the many post about the undefined references error in this forum, I still am not able to solve this matter.

I have created a very simple .bib and .tex file:

The .tex file:

```
% test.tex
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel} 

\title{Bibtex Test}

\begin{document}

Cite this\cite{testcite}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{references}
\end{document}
```

The.bib file:

```
% references.bib
@BOOK{testcite,
   author = "Mustermann Max and Kraut Karl",
   title = "Fixing Bibtex",
   publisher = "Springer",
   year = "2015"
}
```

Both files are located in the same folder and I run my mainfile multiple time. I use TexMaker combined with MikTeX2.9.

There is no error but the simple warning sequence:

LaTeX Warning: Citation `testcite' on page 1 undefined on input line 10
LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.

I assume the error occurs somewhere in my TexMaker settings.
Could you please help me?

Comment: You need to execute `bibtex` an external program. In TeXmaker, I guess, F10 or F11. Do *F6+F10+F6+F6+F7*

Comment: Thank you very much! I really didn't know I had to run bibtex separately. It worked on the first try with  F6+F11+F6+F6+F7 . You are my hero of the day! ;)

Answer (score 20):

The answer is as @Sigur wrote: run

```
(pdf)latex + bibtex + (pdf)latex + (pdf)latex [+ preview]
```

In TeXmaker, this can be done using shortcuts  **F6 + F11 + F6 + F6 [+ F7]**.

Comment: while it's commendable that you've clarified what the solution is to the problem, the alternate approach of asking @Sigur (in a comment) to post an answer is the preferred method here.

Comment: @barbarabeeton, thanks. I edited to improve it.