# Bibliography does not work with beamer. Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: beamer, bibliographies, biber, ubuntu

I've been trying to use bibliography in a beamer document. I have tried in many ways and does not work at all. Here is an example of the document

```
    \documentclass{beamer}
    \usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa]{biblatex}
    \DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
    \addbibresource{References.bib}
    \renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{%
      \ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{2}{\finalandcomma}{}%
      \addspace \&\space}%
    \DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
      references = {Bibliografía Propuesta},
    }        
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[spanish]{babel}
    \usetheme{Singapore}    
    \usefonttheme{serif}
    \usepackage{amsmath}    
    \usepackage{amsthm, amssymb}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
     \cite{*}
     \end{frame}
    \begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
    \printbibliography
    \end{frame}
    \end{document}
```

I have only problems with beamer with other documents works well.

Here an example of one entry of the file References.bib

```
        @article{granger1981,
        title={Some properties of time series data and their use in econometric model specification},
        author={Granger, Clive WJ},
        journal={Journal of econometrics},
        volume={16},
        number={1},
        pages={121--130},
        year={1981},
        publisher={Elsevier}
      }
```

The file gives the following message

```
     Empty bibliography
```

Can someone help me?

ps: I have tried many similar questions on this site, so it is not a duplicate question.

Comment: You must \cite the reference or use \cite{*} for all references.

Comment: Yes, i did it. I'll edit the question

Comment: you have tagged the question bibtex but the markup you are using will not work with bibtex you have backend=biber so you must use biber instead

Comment: So is the problem solved? I'm assuming so from your comments, but not sure.

Comment: No, it's not solved. The problem persist.

Comment: Please show the blg file.

Comment: compiling the above code results in a error `undefined control sequence \end{frame}` after the `\printbibliography`. don't see any reasons for that. I also get a lot of warnings

Comment: Seems like apa style problem. Check authoryear style.

Comment: It is better to load `biblatex` after `babel`, you will also have to change the line `\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}` to `\DeclareLanguageMapping{spanish}{spanish-apa}` if the document language (as set by `babel`) is Spanish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the answer to my question: [Answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/241620/78831). Simply use PdfLaTeX+Bib(la)tex+PdfLaTeX(x2)+View Pdf in the quick compilation settings of TexMaker

Comment: See also [Question mark or bold citation key instead of citation number](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864) and [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864)