# Unable to add citations

Tags: bibtex, citing, texmaker

I have a tex file that goes as:

```
\documentclass[10pt,conference]{IEEEtran}
\input{preamble}
\usepackage{cite}
...
\begin{document}
...
\input{text/introduction.tex}
...
\bibliography{Bib/proj_name}

\end{document}
```

Bib/proj_name.bib:

```
@article{Snorkel2017,
  title =  {Snorkel: Rapid Training Data Creation with Weak Supervision},
  author =  {Alexander Ratner, Stephen H. Bach, Henry Ehrenberg, Jason Fries, Sen Wu, Christopher Ré},
  year =    {2017},
  note =    {\url{https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.10160}}
}
```

text/introduction.tex:

```
\section{Introduction}
\label{sec::intro}
Recently, Snorkel \cite{Snorkel2017} ...
```

**But, I get:**

```
LaTeX Warning: Citation `Snorkel2017' on page 1 undefined on input line 4.
```

Makefile used:

```
LATEX = TEXINPUTS=$(TEXINPUTS):packages pdflatex
PAPER = proj_name

# Run once, then re-run until it's happy
# Input redirected from /dev/null is like hitting ^C at first error
$(PAPER).pdf: $(wildcard *.tex) $(wildcard text/*.tex) $(wildcard *.bib)
    $(LATEX) $(PAPER).tex </dev/null
    bibtex $(PAPER)
    $(LATEX) $(PAPER).tex </dev/null
    $(LATEX) $(PAPER).tex </dev/null
    gs -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress -dEmbedAllFonts=true \
       -dDownsampleColorImages=false -dAutoFilterColorImages=false \
       -dColorImageFilter=/FlateEncode -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=$(PAPER)-embed.pdf \
       $(PAPER).pdf
    cp $(PAPER)-embed.pdf $(PAPER).pdf
```

Of course, I run it using `make`. I have already looked at the possible [duplicate](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/241612/bibtex-there-were-undefined-references), but as you can see in the makefile, I am already doing all that. Can someone please help me out? Thanks...

EDIT:

blg file:

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2019/Debian)
Capacity: max_strings=200000, hash_size=200000, hash_prime=170003
The top-level auxiliary file: proj_name.aux
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file proj_name.aux
You've used 1 entry,
            0 wiz_defined-function locations,
            86 strings with 524 characters,
and the built_in function-call counts, 0 in all, are:
= -- 0
> -- 0
< -- 0
+ -- 0
- -- 0
* -- 0
:= -- 0
add.period$ -- 0
call.type$ -- 0
change.case$ -- 0
chr.to.int$ -- 0
cite$ -- 0
duplicate$ -- 0
empty$ -- 0
format.name$ -- 0
if$ -- 0
int.to.chr$ -- 0
int.to.str$ -- 0
missing$ -- 0
newline$ -- 0
num.names$ -- 0
pop$ -- 0
preamble$ -- 0
purify$ -- 0
quote$ -- 0
skip$ -- 0
stack$ -- 0
substring$ -- 0
swap$ -- 0
text.length$ -- 0
text.prefix$ -- 0
top$ -- 0
type$ -- 0
warning$ -- 0
while$ -- 0
width$ -- 0
write$ -- 0
(There was 1 error message)
```

Comment: `author =  {Alexander Ratner, Stephen H. Bach, Henry Ehrenberg, Jason Fries, Sen Wu, Christopher Ré},` is definitely wrong. Multiple names must always be separated with `and` regardless of the desired output. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36396/35864. The correct input would be `author =  {Alexander Ratner and Stephen H. Bach and Henry Ehrenberg and Jason Fries and Sen Wu and Christopher Ré},`.

Comment: Note that technically, BibTeX can't deal with non-ASCII characters, so `é` should be escaped as `{\'e}`. So you'd need `author =  {Alexander Ratner and Stephen H. Bach and Henry Ehrenberg and Jason Fries and Sen Wu and Christopher R{\'e}},`.

Comment: That all said, you'll definitely want to check out the `.blg` file for more errors or warnings.

Comment: @moewe Regarding first comment, I tried what you wrote, and it's still the same

Comment: @moewe Tried that `{\'e}` thing too, still the same

Comment: The version with `and` is definitely the only correct one, but the error may well be somewhere else. Please show us the `.blg` file.

Comment: @moewe regarding `.blg`, I have this which might be something: `The top-level auxiliary file: facemask.aux
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file facemask.aux`. Edited question to include this

Comment: There you have it: `I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file proj_name.aux`. You need a `\bibliographystyle{...}` call in your document (and only one). With `IEEEtran` you may want to try something like `\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}`. (You probably don't need the `\usepackage{cite}`.)

Comment: @moewe Worked like a charm. Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message from the `.blg` file

```
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file proj_name.aux
```

means that you don't have a `\bibliographystyle` command on your document.

If you want to use BibTeX you will need exactly one `\bibliographystyle{<style>}` command in your document. It doesn't really matter where you put it (it can go into the preamble or the document body), but most people either place it in the preamble next to other bibliography/citation setup or directly next to the `\bibliography` call in the body.

For the `IEEEtran` document class I'd probably use `\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}`.

```
\documentclass[10pt,conference]{IEEEtran}

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
 
\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
\label{sec::intro}
Recently, Snorkel \cite{Snorkel2017} ...

\bibliography{Bib/proj_name}

\end{document}
```

As mentioned in the comments, your `.bib` file should probably be rewritten a bit. The `author`s must be separated with `and` and non-ASCII chars need to be escaped. Furthermore, I'd not want to use `@article` for a paper that hasn't yet been formally published in a journal and is only available on the arXiv.

So my `.bib` would look more like

```
@misc{Snorkel2017,
  title         =  {Snorkel: Rapid Training Data Creation with Weak Supervision},
  author        =  {Alexander Ratner and Stephen H. Bach and Henry Ehrenberg
                    and Jason Fries and Sen Wu and Christopher R{\'e}},
  year          =  {2017},
  howpubslished =  {\url{https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.10160}},
}
```

The `IEEEtran` bibliography styles supports a `url` field, though, so I'd actually prefer

```
@misc{Snorkel2017,
  title  =  {Snorkel: Rapid Training Data Creation with Weak Supervision},
  author =  {Alexander Ratner and Stephen H. Bach and Henry Ehrenberg
             and Jason Fries and Sen Wu and Christopher R{\'e}},
  year   =  {2017},
  url    =  {https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.10160},
}
```

Comment: @AnkitKumar Yup. I just noticed that as well. Fixed.