# MiKTeX - Undefined References and Citations but PDF renders

Tags: cross-referencing, miktex, undefined

I invariably get warnings for undefined references/citations when running even the simplest pieces of code. I am running TeXworks (downloaded along with MiKTeX) on a Windows machine: `MiKTeX-pdfTeX 4.3 (MiKTeX 21.1)`. Here is an MWE (`main.tex`):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction} \label{sec:Intro}
This is the Introduction. 
Section \ref{sec:sec2} is the second section. Section \ref{sec:sec3} is the third section.

\section{Second} \label{sec:sec2}
This is the second section. Here, we cite \cite{Goodwin}.

\section{Third} \label{sec:sec3}
This is the third section. Here, we cite \cite{TVG, Survey}.

\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\bibliography{refs}

\end{document}
```

My BiBTeX file is as follows (`refs.bib`):

```
@BOOK{Goodwin,
author = {Goodwin, G. C. and Sin, K. S.},
title = {Adaptive Filtering Prediction and Control},
publisher = {Dover Publications},
year = {1984}
}

@ARTICLE{TVG,
author = {Moore, K. L. and Chen, Y.-Q. and Bahl, V.},
title = {Monotonically convergent iterative learning control for linear discrete-time systems},
journal = {Automatica},
year = {2005},
volume = {41},
number = {9},
pages = {1529--1537}
}

@ARTICLE{Survey,
author = {Bristow, D. A. and Tharayil, M and Alleyne, A. G.},
title = {{A Survey of Iterative Learning Control}},
journal = {IEEE Control Systems Magazine},
year = {2006},
volume = {26},
number = {3},
pages = {96--114}
}
```

I get the following warnings when I typeset this with the option `pdfLaTeX+MakeIndex+BibTeX` in TeXworks (the `refs.bib` file is being run with the `BibTeX` option):

```
LaTeX Warning: Reference `sec:sec2' on page 1 undefined on input line 6.
LaTeX Warning: Reference `sec:sec3' on page 1 undefined on input line 6.
LaTeX Warning: Citation `Goodwin' on page 1 undefined on input line 9.
LaTeX Warning: Citation `TVG' on page 1 undefined on input line 12.
LaTeX Warning: Citation `Survey' on page 1 undefined on input line 12.
LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.
LaTeX Warning: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right.
LaTeX Warning: Citation `Goodwin' on page 1 undefined on input line 9.
LaTeX Warning: Citation `TVG' on page 1 undefined on input line 12.
LaTeX Warning: Citation `Survey' on page 1 undefined on input line 12.
LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.
LaTeX Warning: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right.
```

No .aux files are generated in the working folder.

Despite multiple re-runs of both `main.tex` and `refs.bib`, these warnings do not vanish. Surprisingly, the PDF renders perfectly, and there is no missing citation or cross-reference (i.e., no question mark in place of references/cross-references). When I try running `main.tex` with just the `pdfLaTeX` option, the warnings for cross-references vanish after running it twice, but warnings for citations remain:

```
LaTeX Warning: Citation `Goodwin' on page 1 undefined on input line 9.
LaTeX Warning: Citation `TVG' on page 1 undefined on input line 12.
LaTeX Warning: Citation `Survey' on page 1 undefined on input line 12.
LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.
```

In this case, a .aux file is generated in the working folder.

I have tried changing the option for `refs.bib` to `pdfLaTeX+MakeIndex+BibTeX`, but it doesn't help. There is no simple `LaTeX` option for compilation.

I feel that this question is an extended version of [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/241612/bibtex-there-were-undefined-references?newreg=173e2e44c34441f5848d7463d8c07652), but with TeXworks in my case, rather than TeXMaker. This problem has been annoying me for a while now, but I have found no suitable fix anywhere. Though the PDF renders properly, I would prefer not to get these warnings as the document simply takes much longer to compile.

Comment: probably texworks has in the profile some clean up setup.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Could you clarify what you mean? My only option in the MiKTeX Console is to remove my entire MiKTeX installation; surprisingly, the option to reset to factory defaults is disabled. I will try uninstalling and reinstalling MiKTeX.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Uninstalling and reinstalling does not fix the problem.

Comment: I meant the pdlatex÷makeindex÷bibtex profile. It probably has a clean up step. Check its definition in texworks.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Apologies for the very late reply. I am unsure what you mean by checking the definition in TeXWorks, could you clarify?