# TeX file with Bib bibliography compiling error

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, pdftex, python

I have the following directory:

```
/run.py
  /doc
     main.tex
     reference.bib
```

In `main.tex`, I have a reference `\bibliography{reference}` that should display the reference section from the bib file. I have also used `\cite{something}` in `main.tex`. All in all, the reference section should be displayed, as I have tested it on Overleaf, and it displays correctly with `main.tex` and `reference.bib` in the same level of directory.

Now I am trying to compile the `.tex` file on my computer with Python. Inside `run.py`, I have the code `subprocess.call(["pdflatex", "./doc/main.tex"])`, and I am running that code in the `run.py` directory. But that code produces errors that the reference cited is not found:

```
LaTeX Warning: Citation `something' on page 1 undefined on input line 104.


! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.117 \end{mcsection}
```

and the compiled PDF file does not show the reference section.

I have tried `\bibliography{reference.bib}`, `\bibliography{doc/reference}`, `\bibliography{./doc/reference.bib}`, they all generate the same error. I have done some [research](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/168312/latex-warning-citation-undefined) where it says that I should compile using `bibtex`, so I tried the following code:

```
    subprocess.call(["pdflatex", "./doc/card.tex"])
    subprocess.call(["bibtex", "./doc/reference.bib"])
    subprocess.call(["pdflatex", "./doc/card.tex"])
    subprocess.call(["pdflatex", "./doc/card.tex"])
```

That still produces the same error.

Comment: Please try to provide a MWEB (minimal working example with bibliography) reproducing the problem. The bibliography part in your log just is a warning and does not seem to be the problem - instead there seems to be some syntax error with your other code.

Answer (score 1):

I was calling `bibtex` on the wrong file. It should have been

```
    subprocess.call(["pdflatex", "./doc/card.tex"])
    subprocess.call(["bibtex", "card"])
    subprocess.call(["pdflatex", "./doc/card.tex"])
    subprocess.call(["pdflatex", "./doc/card.tex"])
```

So it runs bibtex on the generated pdf file.